# Informix and DROP COLUMN if exists

Tags: sql, informix

I am trying to write "re-usable" SQL script with `ADD COLUMN` clause for Informix server. Normally, I can only run it once, because then the column already exists and it cannot be added again. And I cannot just add `DROP column` as prior statement, because it would fail during the first execution. I need something like DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS, but unlike dropping other SQL entities, it is not available for columns.

I can ask system tables whether the column is present in then DB via:

```
SELECT c.colname
  FROM "informix".systables AS t
  JOIN "informix".syscolumns AS c ON t.tabid = c.tabid
 WHERE c.colname = 'col_name' and t.tabname = 'tab_name'
```

plus I found some proposed solutions for workarounds, but I guess they are for different SQL servers, since I cannot figure out how to put it together into valid SQL script acceptable for my Informix.

Any clues? Or is it mission impossible?

Comment: "re-usable" script and adding/dropping columns do not naturally go together.  Perhaps there is another way to solve your problem that doesn't involve changing the structure of your tables.

Comment: Well, there is - to have everything all right for the first attepmt (i am migrating changes from one DB server to another). But "re-usable" in my case means that when I encounter any error during execution, I can simply run the script again without worrying about recovering back to previous state or checking what was already performed...

Answer (score 0):

As things stand, Informix's ALTER TABLE statement has no DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS clause, nor an ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS clause (nor a separate DROP COLUMN statement — though it does have a separate RENAME COLUMN statement).

You would have to wrap the logic to detect whether the column exists in a shell script and decide based on that whether to add the column.  Or, alternatively, you'd have to submit the ADD operation and ignore the 'column already exists' error.

Comment: And is it possible to "ignore error" in plain SQL script? I am using DBeaver for db operations and it stops executing the script on the line where the error is...

Comment: Wrapping into shell script may be tricky, because we are distributing SQL scripts to customer's DB operator and I have no idea how exactly he runs them.

Comment: That depends on DBeaver — or DB-Access, or (my) SQLCMD, or whatever is interpreting the 'plain SQL script'.  I can do it in SQLCMD: `continue push on; error "/dev/null"; ALTER TABLE …;  continue pop;` etc (I need to think about how to reset the error output — probably `error "/dev/stderr";` even on a machine without `/dev/stderr`).

Comment: You may have to start stipulating how the DB Operators run the update/upgrade scripts.

Comment: Just dropping a column: `alter table <table-name> drop <column-name>`